# Attempting to fadein a hidden div depending on $_GET variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am attempting to display a confirmation box, using Jquery, after a user has clicked a delete link. When the delete link is clicked it sends the post_id to the url. As long as this is set and it isn't empty I trigger the animation which will display the hidden confirmation box.

This is what I have so far which isn't currenlty working:

```
// if admin wants to delete a post check for post_id
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && !empty($_GET['post_id'])){

    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['post_id'];
    $animate = true;

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var animate = '.$animate;
    echo '</script>';
}
```

The GET variable is set correctly.

In my jquery file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(animate == true){
        $("#delete_confirm").fadeIn('3000','swing');

    }
});
```

and the confirmatino box:

```
<div id="delete_confirm">
                <p>Please confirm you want to delete this post.</p>
                <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="confirm" />
            </div>
```

Which has `display:none;` set in the style sheet.

Why does it not display when the `animate` variable is set to true?

Thanks

Comment: What order does all this happen in? Are there any Javascript errors? Chances are the `animate` javascript variable isn't reaching accross script tags.

Comment: just a note, this is better: `if( animate === true )`

Comment: The php checks is the `GET` variable is set, if it is it sets `$animate` to true. After this the Jquery does the check on the animate variable, if its set to `true` then the fadein should happen.

Comment: Why don't you move the actual fade-code to be inserted if the animation should occur?

Comment: What's the output of `echo 'var animate = '.$animate;`? Can you find it in the HTML source code?

Comment: Yes, this is not clear at all. Do you do a JSON request to delete the post? Another guess is that you show confirmation dialog on the page and then do HTTP GET and reload the page. And include this JS code on the page. But then I guess it should not be displayed. Anyway now it's unclear what are you doing.

Comment: Could you paste the code for what the admin actually clicks on to start the deletion?

Comment: @Uby this is the output `<script type="text/javascript">var animate = 1</script>`

Comment: Try changing the PHP `$animate = true;` to `$animate = "true";` so that you're outputting `true` in the JavaScript otherwise the type juggling may be converting it to "1" - it shouldn't make any difference as you're not **strictly** evaluating the variable in the JS but...

Comment: @mariusnn That isnt necessary as the get variable is set and does contain the post id.

Comment: @crm try `console.log(animate)` right before the `if(animate == true)` part, see what it outputs

Comment: Just noticed this "Which has display:none; set in the style sheet." ... probably why it doesn't work. jQuery's animate only works with things with numbers... change it to `display: block;` in the stylesheet with `opacity: 0;` then use animate to up the opacity to 1.

Comment: @crm Check my updated answer. It is working now and please don't consider the downvotes, I just posted something before (that was wrong) :-)

Comment: @Oscar Thanks, marked as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Try this, tested and working:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && !empty($_GET['post_id'])){
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['post_id'];
    $animate = true;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simulation</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var prop = {
    animate: "<?php echo $animate; ?>"
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    if(prop.animate == 1){
        $("#delete_confirm").fadeIn('3000','swing');
    }

});
</script>
<body>
<div id="delete_confirm">
    <p>Please confirm you want to delete this post.</p>
    <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="confirm" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo $animate` would output `1`, not `true`. Therefore `(animate === true)` would be false. Also, you need to set the default value of `$animate` somewhere, otherwise it will be empty and there would be a JS syntax error

Comment: In `PHP` it doesn't matter the default value and if it doesn't exist, at javascript side will be `null` or `''`. Then, I know it will print `1` or `0` but you can use `true` or `false` too, try it (at least in `PHP`) that's why I am writing to check the value of `animate` at `javascript` side and then correct the `if` statement.

Comment: If `$animate` is undefined, PHP would print nothing. Then you'll have something like `var animate = $(document)...`, and it's clearly not what you want. Also, if PHP variable `$animate = true`, then `var animate = <?php echo $animate; ?>` would output `var animate = 1`, therefore the JS code `animate === true` would be false, since `animate = 1`.

Comment: `var theBool = 1; alert( theBool === true ? "Yarr" : "Narr" );` Will popup "Narr" whereas `var theBool = 1; alert( theBool == true ? "Yarr" : "Narr" );` will popup "Yarr" ... "===" is a strict evaluation, it evaluates TYPE as well as the value.

Comment: It should work now. Btw: `$animate = 'false'` by default and `$animate = 'true'` within the if statement should be an easier solution

Comment: @Uby Not at all, because you will get a `syntax` error at `javascript` side. I tried doing `$animate = false;` at first, then just `echo` the value at `javascript` side to `var animate` and for some reason the variable gets `empty` when `$animate` is `false`, causing a syntax error at `javascript`. If you look at the `DOM` you will see `var animate = ` or `var animate = ;`. If you are able to confirm me why I get `empty` will be good, that's why I prefer doing the way my answer is, thanks :-)

Comment: @OscarJara I'm talking about `$animate = 'false'`, it means that `$animate`contains a *string*. Not `$animate = false`, where the variable contains a PHP boolean value.

Comment: @Uby Yes, I understand your point of view but why I get `empty` when using `boolean`? Why at javascript side I don't get `0` or something else? but when using `true` I get `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You should unset the `display:none;` property on the div and either call `.fadeOut(0)` on page load, or set its `opacity:0.0;` in the CSS file.

Additionally, instead of including all of this server side code injection stuff, you could handle the GET parameter check on the client side by using the `window.location` object's `search` property, then detect if a particular parameter is set with a regex match. That way you don't have to use any inline JavaScript.

```
var matches = window.location.search.match(/post_id/g);
if(matches && matches.length > 0)
{
// do animation
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Something like this should work, and personally I like doing this more than injecting script tags and inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> The php checks is the GET variable is set, if it is it sets $animate
>   to true. After this the Jquery does the check on the animate variable,
>   if its set to true then the fadein should happen.

For me this is very confusing. Let me try to research this a little bit more.

- You have a page with the confirmation box.
- When user press delete button the confirmation box (`<div id="delete_confirm">`) is show using jQuery script.
- User press the 'delete' button on the page. What happens here? There are two options:

  - You do AJAX request.
  - You do HTTP GET request.

Based on your comments and the code I can guess that you do HTTP GET request. In this case you reload the page. Yes, PHP gets the proper value in `$_GET['post_id']` and the post gets deleted.

But you get completely new HTML page. And on this page the div `<div id="delete_confirm">` is invisible from the very beginning. This is why it is not shown and hidden.

When you look at the source code you can find you JS script `<script type="text/javascript">...` and I beg that the code `$(document).ready(function(){...` works too. But you get it on newly loaded HTML page.

Please correct me if I get you wrong here.

I think that you want to hide the confirmation box you might want to use AJAX. But then you might also want to remove the post from the page by altering the page.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>Quoting the jQuery documentation: "[The .fadeIn() method animates the opacity of the matched elements.](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)"</strike>

What .fadeIn() will do, effectively, is change the css opacity of an element from 0 to 1.

You've stated that in the CSS your element has `display: none;` so all you're actually doing is changing the opacity from `1` (as assuming you've not set that in the CSS) to `1` whilst leaving the display set to `none` ... so it'll never be displayed.

This seems to hold true for `.animate()` which **doesn't** allow you to "animate" the display type (from "none" to "block" - you'd use opacity)... but not for `.fadeIn()` / `.fadeOut()` which **do** allow you to fade a block in/out using the CSS `display` property.

My bad, I was confusing the two.

Comment: Sorry but `fadein()` will display a hidden element.

Comment: hidden, yes, `display: none;` no ... so yeah, technically, you could use `visibility: none;` IIRC.

Comment: crm is right, your answer is incorrect. As a matter of fact, it will set `display` back to `none` on `fadeOut()`

Comment: Oh ... cool; must have been something else I was doing wrong when trying to use `.animate()` on a block with `display: none;` then O.o I'll leave the answer to prove that I can be a numpty but I should put a big strikeout through it :)